# TeX adds a "." at the end of every caption-number in table/figure environment

Tags: formatting, captions

Everytime I use a caption in a `figure` or `table`-environment, TeX adds a single point at the end of the index - like this:

[image]

But it is referenced like this:

[image: referenced]

I'd love to have exactly the same format in my caption as in my reference (simply `5.4`, not `5.4.`) - what is going wrong there? It does the same for `chapters`/`sections` - I'd like to keep these if possible.

I am using `documentclass{scrbook}` and I'd need to keep that.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). What you show us is not the default behaviour, for example  `\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{content...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}` does not print this additional .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
```

or you have somewhere else `numbers=enddot`